# When using a jQuery delegated event handler, how do I get the descendant selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

When using a jQuery delegated event handler, how do I get the descendant selector? For example, in the following table, I want to select the table row that was clicked:

```
<div id='timeline'>
    <table>
        <tr data-somedata=5><td>First Row</td></tr>
        <tr data-somedata=100><td>Another row</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The table is added dynamically, so I'm using a delegated event handler.

```
$("#timeline").on('click', $("tr"), function(event){
    console.debug($(this));       // This selects the entire #timeline
    console.debug(event.target);  // This selects the <td> element, not the <tr>
});
```

How can I select the tr element using the above delegated event handler?

Also, if someone has a JavaScript only solution, that would be great too.

Comment: `$("#timeline").on('click', $("tr"), function(event){` is incorrect syntax. with correct syntax, `$(this)` would be the tr that was clicked. http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Change the code to `$("#timeline").on('click', "tr", function(event)`, then `$(this)` will be the `tr`

Comment: Chaging $("tr") to just "tr" fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the solution (*that I mentioned in comment section*) to helping future readers.

You passed `jQuery object` as `selector`, you need to change the code to following, then `$(this)` will be the `tr`:

```
$('#timeline').on('click', 'tr', function(event){
    var $tr = $(this);

    // play with $tr
});
```

More about `on` here: [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Its not an ID timeline ., its a element so remove # before timliine element

Comment: Bro, read the question's comments. the issue is fixed already.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. I quickly wrote this question, not realizing that I put timeline as an element. Timeline should have been a div with the id='timeline'

Comment: @jabeoogie Happy to help, Could you please edit your question and fix the `id` of `timeline` to help other guys that read this question?

Answer (score 1):

Few errors in your code.

```
1.its `timeline` not `#timeline`
2.you can simply refer as tr it should not be $('tr')
```

except this your code is good

```js
$("timeline").on("click","tr",function(){
   alert($(this).attr('data-somedata'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<timeline>
    <table>
        <tr data-somedata=5><td>First Row</td></tr>
        <tr data-somedata=100><td>Another row</td></tr>
    </table>
</timeline>
```