# Difference between $("li") vs "li"

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's difference between using this with $("li"), and "li"?

```
    $("ul").on("click", $("li"),function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul").append( "<li><a href='#'>Item</a></li>");
    });
```

Comment: See the documentation.  That parameter takes a string.

Comment: The $ just stands for Jquery to make the selection.  If you tried just ("li") it would not select it.

Comment: The difference is that using `$("li")` there is wrong. It should be `"li"`

Comment: It's not "wrong", it just changes the line from being a delegated event handler (one handler set on the UL which deals with all the LI clicks), to a single event handler (one handler set on the UL which deals with clicks on the UL, and has a event.data value that equals $("li").  In your code example, it won't change anything since you are not using the li click for anything.

Comment: @James It's wrong in the sense that it's doing something completely nonsensical and clearly unintentional.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm new, so this got me a little confused. Not sure why people downvote this question. Evidently, we have too many geniuses in here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39417193/2311559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `$("ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {` then the callback will be called whenever an `li` element in the `ul` will be called. If you click on `ol` in the example blow then nothing will be appended, only if you click at `li`:

```js
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("ul").append("<li>Item</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>li</li>
  <ol>ol</ol>
</ul>
```

Writing `$("ul").on("click", $("li"), function(e) {` will omit the filter because it is not a string (the `$("li")` is used for `event.data` instead), so for your code it is essentially the same as writing `$("ul").on("click", function(e) {`. For this example the element will be added for any click on the `ul` or its descendance:

```js
$("ul").on("click", $("li"), function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("ul").append("<li>Item</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>li</li>
  <ol>ol</ol>
</ul>
```